# How to use Redirect in React Router v4 in right way?

Tags: react-router-v4

I have routes like that:

```
<Router history={this.props.history}>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" name="Home" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/colors" component={Palette} />
    <Route path="/icons" component={Icons} />
    <Route path="/forms" component={Forms} />
    <Route path="/other" component={Other} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Switch>
      <Redirect from="/dashboard" to="/dashboard/my-account" />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/my-account" />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/service-request" />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/payments" />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/settings" />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

When user goes to `/dashboard` I want to redirect them to `/dashboard/my-account`.

So in my case all `/dashboard/*` routes redirect to `/dashboard/my-account`

How to use React Router v4 similar to  feature in the prev. version?

Thanks.

Comment: The goal of `Redirect` is to redirect **if** some condition is true - otherwise, why not simply take the user directly to `/dashboard/my-account`?

Comment: What if user will type address manually like `example.com/dashboard`?

Comment: What if the user types `/account` or `/admin`? Why would a user type a random URL? Better yet, why not just have the account page at `/dashboard`?

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this situation too. Here's what I did with the `<Switch>`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => <Redirect to="dashboard/my-account" />} />
  <Route path="/dashboard/my-account" />
  <Route path="/dashboard/service-request" />
  <Route path="/dashboard/payments" />
  <Route path="/dashboard/settings" />
</Switch>
```

With this. `/dashboard` will redirect to `/dashboard/my-account` but `/dashboard/foo` wont match anything. I recommend adding a `NotFound` component or something to catch the 404s.

Comment: I was able to use this when I had a ternary with root, where if signed in it went to dashboard, if not it redirected to sign in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So anyone who still has issues with this can just use the strict boolean on the Redirect component like so:

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect strict from="/dashboard" to="/dashboard/my-account" />
  <Route exact path="/dashboard/my-account" />
  <Route exact path="/dashboard/service-request" />
  <Route exact path="/dashboard/payments" />
  <Route exact path="/dashboard/settings" />
</Switch>
```

This will ensure only `/dashboard` gets redirected to `/dashboard/my-account`